# how use kinect(openni) in opencv - linux(ubuntu14)

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, cmake, openni

I trying to use kinect on OPENCV and I realized that openni is the best library for kinect
but I could not find the latest version of it(Because the site is closed)
and i am using openni1.5.4 nite1.5.2 sensorkinect5.1.2.1 and opencv2.4.9 in ubuntu14.04LST

kinect installed correctly and i can run sample project from openni folder

now i want to use openni in opencv project, like this

> VideoCapture sensor1;
>   sensor1.open(CV_CAP_OPENNI);

but It doesn't work and I noticed this error can be from cmake variable so i remake opencv build files with

> cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON  **-D WITH_OPENNI=ON** ..

and in terminal i can see

> OpenNI:                      YES (ver 1.5.4, build 0)
>   --     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  YES (/usr/lib/libXnCore.so)

but when i use

> cout << cv::getBuildInformation();

in my project , i get this

> OpenNI:                      NO
>       OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO

Where is the problem and What is the solution?

I thank you in advance

Comment: have you tried ccmake to double check that the option is on?

Comment: @api55 ----- Thank you very much for your attention to my question-------   

yes , i checked "ccmake .." and the WITH_OPENNI variable is ON and other openni variable have correct values

Comment: that is weird... I can give you is an alternative to your problem. Instead of using openni integrated with opencv use opencv and openni as separated libraries. OR try to check where in the make it compiles the openni wrappers to see if there is an error or something, also make sure with ccmake that the directory is valid for openni.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was solved

i installed libfreenect like this

> mkdir -p ~/Developer/Work 
>   cd ~/Developer/Work
>   git clone https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect
>   cd libfreenect
>   git checkout tags/v0.3.0

- NOTE: Tested with libfreenect stable release v0.3.0
- Build and install:

> cd ~/Developer/Work/libfreenect mkdir build cd build cmake .. -D BUILD_OPENNI2_DRIVER=ON 
>  make sudo make install
>       cd  ~/Developer/Work/libfreenect
>   mkdir build
>   cd build
>   cmake .. -D BUILD_OPENNI2_DRIVER=ON
>   make
>   sudo make install

- Add to library path:

> sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/custom.conf

Add

> /usr/local/lib/
>  /usr/local/lib/OpenNI2-FreenectDriver/

And

> sudo ldconfig

Test with glview:

> sudo glview

in cmake i use BUILD_OPENNI2_DRIVER=ON but i didn't install openni2 , i use openni1.5.4

and Be sure to use a computer not VMware  (i couldn't get stream on VMware)